# Bootstrap - row overflow with columns (scroll)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

is there a possibility to make something like:

```
<div className="row">
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div className="col-sm-4">1</div>
</div>
```

BUT i want a overflow , not a new Line

Thanks for help!

Comment: You mean, horizontal scroll?

Comment: yes, exactly, it work with text and so on ... but not with columns .., whenever i add more columns then the size of 12 .. it creates a new Row or lets call it Line ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap has the [`flex-nowrap`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#wrap) class available for this purpose.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row flex-nowrap">
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen Version](https://codepen.io/3rror404/pen/NWGEVBJ)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`flex-wrap: nowrap`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) to `row` with [bootstrap class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#wrap) `flex-nowrap`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row flex-nowrap">
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help